# Should it be Has or had?

Tags: past-tense

May I know should it be has or had lost?
Lucy did not have any money for lunch as she had or has lost her wallet in the morning. 
Thank you.

Comment: Idiomatically it would usually be ***neither*** - just say ***as she lost her wallet***.

Answer (score 1):

The choice of tense really depends on the context although there are lots of grey areas and room for personal preference.

Let's imagine first that the speaker is talking shortly after lunch on the day concerned. The speaker is likely to say either:

> Lucy did not have any money for lunch as she **has** lost her wallet.

In this setting, Lucy's wallet is still lost. The sentence does not say when she lost it.

Or:

> Lucy did not have any money for lunch as she lost her wallet this morning.

Here the past tense is used with a time reference to specify when she lost her wallet although the present perfect (has lost) would also serve if the event is recent.

The past perfect (had lost) is most often used to show that one event took place before another in the past. For example:

> Lucy did not have any money for lunch as she had lost her wallet that morning before she boarded the bus.

The sentence reads more easily by changing **in the morning** to **that morning** to emphasise that it's in the past. But the change is not essential.

**Had lost** (past perfect) makes it clear that the loss took place before she caught (past simple) the bus on the morning concerned.

However, it's also perfectly acceptable to keep both verbs **lost** and **boarded** in the past tense.

So, as a guide, we generally omit the time reference after **has**.

**It has happened** means that the past event has an impact on the present.

**It happened** simply means that it's an event in the past.

**It had happened** indicates that the event took place before some other event in the past.

Answer (score 0):

It depends when this happened: recently (in the last few moments), or awhile ago.

- “Lucy **had** lost her pencil just before last week’s quiz started, so she got a zero.
- “This week, she **has** promised to be ready.”

In your example, you can just say:

- Lucy has no money for lunch, as she lost her wallet this morning.

There is no need to use “had lost” unless something else is going to happen in the sentence.

- Lucy has no money for lunch today, as she had just lost her wallet this morning when the school bus came.

If the entire sentence is in the past, “had” is fine:

- Lucy had no money for lunch that day, as she had lost her wallet that morning.

Comment: If the morning was while ago, it should be had lost?

Comment: If the entire sentence is in the past, “had” makes sense. I’ve updated my answer above.